# Resolver letras repetidas adyacentes o contiguas en un array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

tuve una entrevista para una empresa que dentro de la prueba técnica me pusieron el siguiente ejercicio.

Dado el array `let array = ['ab', 'abb', 'abbabbabbaa']` eliminar las letras contiguas repetidas y devolver el array ordenado de mayor a menor.

**La salida esperada era**: `['abababa','ab','ab']`

Pero no pude resolverlo, Sabía que debía usar `map` y `filter` pero no supe como para solucionarlo. Mi solucion fue iterar cada una de las palabras con map y convertir a un conjunto cada una para eliminar las repetidas pero eliminaba todas las letras repetidas de cada posición dejando algo como lo siguiente `['ab','ab','ab']`.

mi solución fue:

```js
let data = ["ab", "abb", "abbabbabbaa"]

const newData = data.map((el, index) => [...new Set(el)])

console.log(newData)
```

Como lo resolverían ustedes? no quisiera encontrarme devuelta con el mismo problema sin una solución! Gracias de ante mano

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la salida correcta? Supongo que es `['ab', 'a', 'aaa']` -sin ordenar-. Adicional, sería bueno que colocaras tu intento a modo de [mcve].

Comment: si perdon, ya completo la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero dejemos claro el funcionamiento de [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Según la documentación:

> El objeto **Set** permite almacenar valores únicos de cualquier tipo, incluso valores primitivos u referencias a objetos.

Lo anterior quiere decir que `Set` solo almacenará **valores únicos**, es decir, si crear un ser a partir de `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]`, la salida será `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. Es por eso que en tu código, la salida siempre es `ab`.

Volviendo al problema, no estás tan mal con la idea de usar `.map()`, solo que te faltó desarrollar un poco más la lógica, es entendible, me ha pasado en las entrevistas. Lo que podrías hacer por ejemplo, sería recorrer cada letra del string como si de un array se tratara, crear un array auxiliar en el que vayas insertando el elemento, si y solo si, es distinto al último elemento en el array, es decir, si el último elemento es `a` y el que evaluas es `a`, entonces no lo insertas. Contrario, si el último elemento es `a` y estás evaluando `b`, entonces no se trata de un elemento igual y puedes insertarlo al nuevo array.

En el ejemplo se asume que cada palabra tiene una longitud mayor a 2, pero lo ideal sería que validaras eso para evitar problemas con el for (no estoy validando). Se empieza desde el segundo elemento (indice `1`) y evaluas con respecto al anterior hasta recorrer cada elemento. Al final, haces un `.join()` de ese array para obtenerlo como string y no como array.

```js
const array = ['ab', 'abb', 'abbabbabbaa'];

function deleteConsecutive(array) {
  return array.map((word) => {
    const newWord = [word[0]];
    for (let i = 1; i < word.length; i++) {
      if (word[i - 1] !== word[i]) {
        newWord.push(word[i]);
      }
    }
    return newWord.join('');
  });
}

console.log(deleteConsecutive(array));
```

Podrías lograr algo similar usando [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) y [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) (para obtener el último carácter). De este modo te olvidas de validar la longitud de la cadena y también puedes trabajar directamente con un string.

```js
const array = ['ab', 'abb', 'abbabbabbaa'];

const deleteConsecutive = (array) => {
  return array.map(word => [...word].reduce((newWord, c) => {
    if (newWord.slice(-1) !== c) {
      newWord += c;
    }
    return newWord;
  }, ''));
}

console.log(deleteConsecutive(array));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios, creo que la segunda opción era la esperada. Creo que la finalidad era una solución mas orientada al paradigma funcional y no tan imperativa. Sin embargo sus comentarios me han  ayudado para leer mas sobre estos metodos. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Una solución es recorrer cada cadena desde el segundo elemento (si tiene más de un elemento), y comparar el iterando con el elemento anterior. Al final se trata de hacerlo tal como lo harías en lápiz y papel.

Por ejemplo:

Primero almacenamos el primer carácter (`cadena[0]`) en otra variable de tipo cadena llamada `salida`.

Si `cadena` tiene más de un elemento, iteramos desde `i` igual a 1 hasta `cadena.length - 1`.

En cada iteración comparamos `cadena[i]` con `cadena[i - 1]`.

Si son iguales, continuamos a la siguiente iteración.

Si son diferentes, concatenamos el carácter `cadena[i]` con `salida`.

Finalmente devolvemos salida.

En código se aprecia de la siguiente forma:

```js
let data = ["ab", "abb", "abbabbabbaa"];

const eliminaRepetidos = cadena => {
  if(!(cadena && typeof cadena === 'string')) return cadena;
  let salida = cadena[0];
  if(cadena.length) {
    for(let i = 1; i < cadena.length; ++i) {
      if(cadena[i] !== cadena[i - 1]) {
        salida = salida.concat(cadena[i]);
      }
    }
  }
return salida;
}

data.forEach(cad => {
  console.log(eliminaRepetidos(cad));
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte es de mucha utilidad para seguir mejorando y estudiando al respecto.